# how to transfer data between different hadoop clusters in Java application?

Tags: hadoop

My sample java application is to read data from one hadoop cluster and store it in another hadoop cluster(say A, B each).

this is sample code to read data from A.

```
    StringBuilder result=new StringBuilder();
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
    FileStatus[] status=fs.listStatus(new Path("/result/test1"));
    for(FileStatus file:status){
        System.out.println(file.getPath().toString());
        if(file.getPath().toString().contains("part")){
            FSDataInputStream inputStream=fs.open(file.getPath());
            String inputString;
            while((inputString=inputStream.readLine())!=null){
                result.append(inputString);
            }
        }
    }
```

code below is to get access to B

```
    conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://10.101.51.221:9000");
    conf.set("mapred.job.tracker", "hdfs://10.101.51.221:9001");
    fs=FileSystem.get(conf);
```

This sample java application contains A's hadoop/conf/* in its buildpath to get access to A and I thought I can also access to B by just changing fs.default.name and mapred.job.tracker but it doesn't work. Error message was like

```
13/08/21 14:41:08 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: Already tried 0 time(s).
...
13/08/21 14:41:26 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: Already tried 9 time(s).
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Call to server failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
```

Any tip about this problem will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DistCp (distributed copy) is a tool used for large inter/intra-cluster copying.

- bash$ hadoop distcp hdfs://src:8020/foo/bar hdfs://dest:8020/bar/foo

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/distcp.html#cpver

In java application you can use **org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp** class

Comment: Could you give me some more detail? I'm using r1.2.0 and looked over api in http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.0/api/index.html document but found nothing about org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp class